# load file from local path from web server jetty

Tags: html, static, jetty

I want load a file from the file system in a web server (Jetty).
I used `eXist-db` and this uses Jetty.
I changed `jetty.xml` and inserted `resourceBase` element into the resource handler,
but this change does not work in Windows. But it does work correctly in Linux.

I want to load a file from any path in Windows with `iFrame`.
For example :

```
<iframe src="c:\newfolder\test.pdf" />
<iframe src="d:\newfolder\test.pdf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not use absolute file paths e.g. `src="c:\newfolder\test.pdf"` in a webpage served from a web server such as Jetty.

Instead you should use the URL to the resource on the web server, perhaps something like `src="http://localhost:8080/newfolder/test.pdf"`

Comment: If you are using an absolute path then this has no relationship with Jetty or eXist-db.

Comment: This is not an eXist-db or Jetty question. However the src attribute of an iframe expects a URI not a file path, you should probably use something like file://c:/newfolder/test.pdf

Comment: i can set "resourceBase" in "jetty.xml" etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308608/serve-files-from-folder-outside-web-application-in-jetty. this not work in windows.